# Cython to build a python script

Tags: python, cython

Trying to get cython to run and I get this issue after following the quick start guide:

```
$ ~/midt $ ./setup.py build_ext --inplace
running build_ext
building 'proc' extension
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c proc.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/proc.o
proc.c:2511:16: error: ‘initproc’ redeclared as different kind of symbol
 PyMODINIT_FUNC initproc(void); /*proto*/
                ^
In file included from /usr/include/python2.7/Python.h:80:0,
                 from proc.c:16:
/usr/include/python2.7/object.h:320:15: note: previous declaration of ‘initproc’ was here
 typedef int (*initproc)(PyObject *, PyObject *, PyObject *);
               ^
error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Here are my version numbers and stuff:

```
$ ~/midt $ python --version
Python 2.7.6
$ ~/midt $ cython --version
Cython version 0.23.5
$ ~/midt $ uname -a
Linux xxxxx 3.13.0-37-generic #64-Ubuntu SMP Mon Sep 22 21:28:38 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the issue is:

1. Python requires the function to initialise a C module initialisation to be called `init<module_name>` (where you substitute your module name). (Python 3 uses a slightly different form).
2. You've called your module `proc`.
3. Cython has thus created a function called `initproc` to be defined when your module is imported.
4. Python defines a typedef called `initproc` internally, which conflicts with the Cython generated `initproc` used to initialise your module.

The solution is to call your module something other than `proc`. It isn't an ideal solution, but there aren't too many other options.

---

One of the reasons Python 3 picked a different form `PyInit_<module_name>` was that the Python 2 form was known to cause a few conflicts (see https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3121/#entry-point-name-conflicts).